# Selenium RemoteWebDriver set preferred Locales

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I'm trying to automate Chrome, Ie, Edge and Firefox using a Selenium Grid Setup.
The Hub is set on another machine my Selenium tests have no access to.

Some of my tests require to change the browser's preferred language.

For Firefox and Chrome i found the possibility of adding the options to the capabilities.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--lang=en");
getCapabilites().setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Is there a similar way to do the same for InternetExplorer and Edge?
Or Maybe a workaround i can use to set the locales?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to all the chrome capabilities, but it work only for a browser language that sending in header: 'accept-language'.

If want to change chrome locale fully, you've need to change system preferences language.
In MacOSX I'm just change locale of "Google Chrome"

```
 defaults write -app "Google Chrome" AppleLanguages -array ru-RU
```

Answer (score 0):

Try those capabilites (works for me)

```
prefs: {
  intl: { accept_languages: acceptLang },
},
args: ["lang=" + acceptLang],
```